# My graph contraction algorithm in Python behaves strangely

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I've written some code for this problem. (python27)

Graph is represented as dictionary with frozenset keys and sets of frozensets:

```
sample_graph = {frozenset([7]): set([frozenset([4]), frozenset([5]), frozenset([3])]), frozenset([5]): set([frozenset([7]), frozenset([2]), frozenset([1])]), frozenset([3]): set([frozenset([7]), frozenset([4]), frozenset([2]), frozenset([1])]), frozenset([6]): set([frozenset([4]), frozenset([2]), frozenset([1])]), frozenset([4]): set([frozenset([6]), frozenset([7]), frozenset([3]), frozenset([1])]), frozenset([1]): set([frozenset([6]), frozenset([4]), frozenset([5]), frozenset([2]), frozenset([3])]), frozenset([2]): set([frozenset([6]), frozenset([5]), frozenset([3]), frozenset([1])])}
```

Output should be a graph with only two nodes which are the frozensets of all the nodes in the graph. At this point it runs into KeyError.

```
def kargerMinCut(graph):
if len(graph) == 2:
    return graph
u = random.choice(graph.keys())   # u and v are frozensets, idea is that they form
v = random.choice(list(graph[u])) # a clique in a single frozenset
for node in graph:
    if node != u and node != v:
        links = graph[node]       
        if u in links or v in links:
            links.add(frozenset(tuple(u | v))) # combine u and v to form one link
            links.discard(u)                   # delete old links to u and v
            links.discard(v)            
            graph[node] = links
graph[u | v] = graph[u] | graph[v]             # new key for u and v 
del graph[u], graph[v]                         # u and v are no longer needed
return kargerMinCut(graph)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation to match the code you are running. Also, it would help if you supplied your input, the expected return value, and the actual return value.

Comment: indentation is only violated on the first line where def is. I will add sample graph input, but it is random algorithm, so I can't tell what the output going to be exactly.

Comment: @AndrewSokolowski In that case, I'd make a small demo graph and choose specific `u` and `v`. It's good to start with an example where you know what should happen, to help you decide whether your code is working as intended: "One day Alice came to a fork in the road and saw a Cheshire cat in a tree. *Which road do I take?* she asked. *Where do you want to go?* was his response. *I don't know*, Alice answered. *Then*, said the cat, *it doesn't matter.*" : )

Comment: you are totally right. because of my impatience I spent all day  trying to make it work on the actual problem with 200 vertices graph, which have deeply hidden the bugs from me. after carefully studying the output from much more smaller graph error was found within minutes. learning the hard way:) thnx for help and the quote, it fully describes what I was doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be the use of the `is` keyword. Note that in python, `is` only returns true when the two arguments refer to the *exact* same object (equivalent to `char* == char*` in C++. The `==` operator returns true if the contents are the same (equivalent to `string == string` in C++).

So rather than `is not` try `!=`.

I once had this identical problem when traversing elements in a graph in python. : )

PS-- Also, I'd write the following line as a full `if`:

```
links.add(frozenset(tuple(u | v))) if u in links or v in links else None
```

Comment: Thnx! I tried what you advised but unfortunately loop still doesn't change a dime

Comment: What did the problem end up being?

Comment: `if node != u and node != v` prevented of getting rid of links from `u` to `v` in `u node` and vise versa, which caused a key error eventually. this condition should have been only here `links.add(frozenset(tuple(u | v)))`